# How do I set authetication state change in Vue?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, vuex

After logging in, I want to set the state that user is logged in. Where do I enter this code?
I also have a menu component with Hello, Sign in. I'd like to change this to Hello {{user.email}}, Sign out when user is signed in.

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**In main.js**

```
let app = '';

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if(!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store: store,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
})
```

**to help with your component**

```
<template>

  <div>
    <span v-if="user">Hello {{user.email}}</span>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
 
  import firebase from 'firebase'

  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        user: null,
      }
    },
    beforeMount(){
      this.getUser()
    },
    methods: {
      getUser: function() {
        if(firebase.auth().currentUser) {
          this.user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        }
        else {
          this.user = null
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When I add this to main.js I get error   `32:15  error    'Vue' is not defined                                        no-undef`

Comment: import Vue from 'vue'